# In dart, when is constructor used and when it isn't?

Tags: class, dart, input, methods, constructor

```
void main() {
  Car myCar = Car(3);
  print(myCar.numberofdoors);
}

class Car{
  Car(numberofdoors);
  int numberofdoors = 5;
 }
```

***output: 5***
This seems pretty logical ...

```
void main() {
  Car myCar = Car(numberofdoors: 3);
  print(myCar.numberofdoors);
}

class Car{
  @override
  Car({this.numberofdoors});
  int numberofdoors = 5;
}
```

***output: 3***
But this is quite unexpected, please explain ...

Comment: Constructors are always invoked to create an instance of a class.  You cannot construct an object without one.  Your first example prints `5` because the `Car` constructor does not do anything with the argument, so `myCar.numberofdoors` is the default value of 5.  In the second example, your constructor does initialize `myCar.numberofdoors` with the supplied argument, so it's `3`.

Comment: Understood! Thank you very much, Sir!